# OOP JavaScript - Create Custom Div Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, custom-component

I'm just starting out with OOP in JavaScript. I want to create a custom "panel." Here is what I have so far:

```
function ShinyPanel(css, attributes)
{
    this.container = $(document.createElement("div")).addClass("shinyPanel");

    this.titleBar = $(document.createElement("div")).addClass("shinyPanelTitleBar").appendTo(this.container);
    this.topShine = $(document.createElement("div")).addClass("shinyPanelTopShine").appendTo(this.container);
    this.leftShine = $(document.createElement("div")).addClass("shinyPanelLeftShine").appendTo(this.container);
    this.content = $(document.createElement("div")).addClass("shinyPanelContent").appendTo(this.container);

    if (!css) css = {};
    if (!attributes) attributes = {};

    this.css = css;
    $(this.container).css(this.css);

    this.title = attributes["title"];
    $(this.titleBar).html(this.title);
}
```

Now I can instantiate this object and append it to the body via something like this:

```
var panel = new ShinyPanel({position:"absolute", top:"25%", width:"300px", height:"200px"}, {title:"Test"});
$("body").append(panel.container);
```

My question is, is there a way for me to make the object itself a div, thus eliminating the need for a "container" div? Then I could just call `$("body").append(panel);`.

It's not that its much trouble for me to have the container div there, it's more just for me...wanting to learn the right way to do things.

I tried `this = document.createElement("div");`, but I got an error: `invalid assignment left-hand side`.

Comment: Does `return this.container;` not work? :)

Comment: I didn't think of that at the time, but after @PaulPhillips suggeted it in his answer, I am trying it and for some reason, appending elements to panel.content isn't working. Still messing around with it to see if I can figure it out, though.

Comment: I would suggest checking out how jQuery UI works then, since that's roughly what you're trying to do I think.

Comment: @Jack: I think I am going to use jQuery UI. Thank you for the suggestion. If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is basically what the UI framework is able to accomplish.

Check out the widget factory documentation to get started:

http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest having a `ShinyPanel` method that handles this.  Tell, don't ask.

```
function ShinyPanel(css, attributes) {
...
   this.appendTo = function (to) {
      $(to).append(this.container);
   }
```

Comment: This would be a better solution than I currently have, but the other issue that I forgot to mention in the original question was setting properties on it also requires me to set them on the container: `$(panel.container).attr("id", "myPanel");`. Any better suggestion with that in mind?

Comment: You could add a `attr` function that redirected all calls to the container.

Comment: Yeah, but it's not just `attr`, either. I might want to call `$(panel).css(...)` and a boat-load of other available functions...I don't want to have to override all of them.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the suggestions, but it looks like jQuery UI might be a better solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could return `this.container` directly from your constructor function, assuming you're not going to use any of the other properties you added to it.

To do this, I *think* you would have to change it to be a factory method, rather than a constructor (i.e. don't use `new` anymore - although there is more to it than that).

Comment: I'm trying this now, but running into trouble where anything I add to the `content` div isn't showing up. Perhaps I need to research a bit more and use a different method of creating a custom object.

Comment: If you're using anything besides `container`, what I suggested won't work.  Since you're trying to do OOP, I think I've given you a pretty poor answer, honestly. Explosion Pills answer is a much better idea, and there is probably some plugin-way to auto-override all the jquery functions. Though I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

When all you want to do is append it to body, instead of returning an object, you could just return a string with your panel.

Something like this:

```
function shinyPanel(css, attributes) {
    ... all the stuff you did before
    return this.container
}
```

Furthermore, if you want to achieve some speed in that `shinyPanel` function of yours, you could try to add strings of your markup and then only use `append` once.

Also have a look into using an array as a holder for your return string and then use `.join('')` when you return it.

More info: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly

Comment: I don't think I want it to return a string. I want the panel's properties to be easily modifiable, even after creating the object. For example, I want to be able to do this: `var panel = new ShinyPanel(); panel.title = "Test";` I know it won't exactly work that way right now...that's next on my list of things to get working.