# JQuery UI Widget Factory alternatives

Tags: javascript, oop, widget, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I've just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299238/oop-javascript-create-custom-div-object) that is asking exactly what I was looking for: a way to construct in OOP a widget that can present complex DOM aggregate.

I'm not using JQuery so I'm asking alternative to this widget factory, or at least some example/repository where I can read something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative would be dojo's dijit widgets:

http://dojotoolkit.org/